# The abc conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I saw this article [here](http://www.nature.com/news/the-biggest-mystery-in-mathematics-shinichi-mochizuki-and-the-impenetrable-proof-1.18509?WT.mc_id=SFB_NNEWS_1508_RHBox), which talk about a Japanese mathematician that claims to have solved one of the most important problems in his field: the **abc conjecture**.
Please, could someone explain to me, in simple words, what is this problem and why it is so important? Thank you!

Comment: In the article, have you read the section that start with "**Primal importance**
The abc conjecture refers to numerical expressions of [...]"? If so, what sort of explanation would you like -- more in depth, at which level? (e.g., compared to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture))

Comment: You might find helpful the MathOverflow Question from 2013, [Philosophy behind Mochizuki's work on the ABC conjecture](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106560/philosophy-behind-mochizukis-work-on-the-abc-conjecture).  As for the [ABC conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), which is a specific conjecture that would be confirmed by that work, you will find several previous posts under the Related section to the right (on the desktop version of the site).  E.g. [Can someone explain the ABC conjecture to me?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196024/).

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the article cited doesn't actually state the conjecture; merely a description that if a and b tend to be divisible by large powers of primes a + b = c won't be.  Which is a very concise "feel" of the conjecture but one can hardly blame the OP for thinking it is vague.  The wikipedia article is good though.